# Spine.js and two controllers

Tags: spine.js

Immediately declare: not to consider this issue as a real application. Everything is done exclusively for the purpose of self-education and learning spine.js

Secondly, I know about the relation. I do not want to use, because world is wider than simple relationships. As an example, a page with the article you want to show users that are online now, or all those who participated in writing the article.

Imagine an ordinary application that displays a list of posts that you can create, show, edit, and delete. All on spine.js, everything works fine. Based on spine.rails3 application.
Then I added the Comment model with fields post_id and body. And added button Comments on the veiw Show. All I want - is to load  comments for this article by pressing button Comments.
My comment.js.coffee:

```
    class App.Comment extends Spine.Model
      @configure 'Comment', 'post_id', 'body', 'created_at', 'updated_at'
      @extend Spine.Model.Ajax

      @fetch_comments: (id) =>
        params =
          data: {post_id: id}
          url: '/comments/fetch'
          processData: true

        @ajax().fetch(params)
        true
```

In Rails controller:

```
def fetch
  @comments = Comment.where("post_id = ?", params[:post_id])
  respond_with @comments
end
```

In the chrome console everything works fine:

```
App.Comment.fetch_comments(11)
App.Comment.all()
```

And receiving from the server all the comments with post_id = 11.

And my problem is that I do not know how to do the same thing from the controller Posts :-(
In my posts.js.coffee:

```
class Show extends Spine.Controller
events:
  ......
  'click [data-type=show]': 'comments'
comments: ->
  @log(@item.id)
  new App.Comments(@item.id)
```

Аnd here the problem....How to implement controller App.Comments, so it is loaded from the server need comments? 
Now my contoller looks like:

```
Comment = App.Comment

class Index extends Spine.Controller

  constructor: (id)->
    super
    **App.Comment.fetch_comments(id)**   


class App.Comments extends Spine.Stack
  className: 'comments stack'

  controllers:
    index: Index

  routes:
    # '/comments/new':      'new'
    '/comments/':          'index'

  className: 'stack comments'
```

And on a selected line is not working. I do not know what to do...

The main question is how to call a controller from another controller with a specific parameter, and the results are displayed in the main controller?

Maybe this is noob question, but I hope for your help.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i see you are using a spine stack. the stack gets passed in the Controllers which are managed by the stack. so inside `Index` you can access the parent stack with `@stack`.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not quite understand. How exactly to use the **@stack** in the **Index** controller? How  I  can to access the **post_id** in the Index controller? In App.Comments, of course.

Comment: I understood about the @stack. I'll try to use. Thanx.